# PHP fgetcsv() with french characters

Tags: php, fgetcsv

I have been using fgetcsv() for reading a csv file which contains some french text, but php is  not reading text in right manner. for example if french text is "Accessoires pour téléphone mobile" it reads this text as "Ac" only. I have set the locale at the top of script

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR.UTF-8');
```

please help.

Comment: Are you sure it's the *reading* that fails and not the *output*? Can you provide some more info on what you are doing?

Comment: yes maybe its reading that fails. i am using function as $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024); and then storing info in a variable $product_id = $line_of_text[0];

Comment: And you have `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in your `<head>`? `setlocale` is less important.

Comment: Is there a line longer then `1024` bytes?